# Unity Application.Loadlevel is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using soomla package for in-app purchasing and I met a strange error to build my game, and it is very difficult to solve for me.

In the callback function `OnMarketPurchase`, I call this code.

```
public void OnMarketPurchase(PurchaseableVirtualItem pvi, string payload, Dictionary<string,string> extra){
   if(pvi.ItemId == "purchaseable_item_id"){
     GlobalScript.setLiteVersionFlag();
     if(GoogleADS!=null)
        GoogleADS.SendMessage("DestroyBanner");
    Application.loadLevel("GameScene1");
   }
}
```

In here, GoogleADS is a gameobject that is published on `Start()` function.

I could see the result of `GlobalScript.setLiteVersionFlag()` and `GoogleADS.sendMessage`.

But, `loadlevel` is not working. I don't know why this happens?

Comment: In what way is it not working, does it give an error message?

Answer (score 2):

You have not shared the complete code, so I can only guess -

1. `if(pvi.ItemId == "purchaseable_item_id")` is not evaluating as `true`
2. `OnMarketPurchase` is not getting called
3. `GameScene1` is named incorrectly
4. `GameScene1` has not been added to ["Scenes in build"](http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/BuildSettings34.png)

Comment: I solved. I`ve received callback in OnItemPurchased function. But I am not sure it is correct way. Because I received callback in OnMarketPurchase on other scene. However it is solved. Thanks for your aply.